# Producer / Consumer Solution

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am implementing a solution to the producer consumer problem using semaphores and have so far developed this code which has the producer and consumer implemented.

```
#define N 100               
typedef int semaphore;
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore empty = N;
semaphore full = 0;
void producer(void)
{
    int item;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        produce_item(&item);
        down(&empty);
        down(&mutex);
        enter_item(item);
        up(&mutex);
        up(&full);
    }
}
void consumer(void)
{
    int item;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        down(&full);
        down(&mutex);
        remove_item(&item);
        up(&mutex);
        up(&empty);
        consume_item(item);
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to think of how to implement the main which prints the number every time an item is produced/consumed.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: Start some producer threads, (maybe loop around a PC queue push of some pointer/whatever and sleep call), and some consumer threads, (maybe loop around a queue pop and printf received pointer/whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest printing the messages after calling `enter_item` and `remove_item` . This problem is best solved using threads but for your implementation, try to produce 'x' amount of items(till it's full) and then let the consumer consume them.

Comment: So is it just a case of inserting a printf statement after enter_item and remove_item? So:

Comment: Well for the printing part i think yes. You get the number that you entered/removed and print it with a suitable message like "Item `x` produced and added to the stack of `N` "  or " `x` items produced out of `N` . You do the same for removed items.

Comment: Although, as for the main part, think of that. One point of the producer/consumer problem is to make sure that the producer won't  add an item if  the buffer is full and that the consumer won't try to remove data from it if it's empty. Thinking of that, make examples to cover some possible results, either good or bad.